# mix-blend-mode: color; is not working for <video> on iOS and Mac devices

Tags: google-chrome, safari, cross-browser, html5-video, mix-blend-mode

## **Structure of hero banner:**

```
<div className="hero-banner">
  <video autoPlay muted loop playsInline className="hero-banner__video">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
  <div className="hero-banner__overlay"></div>
  <div className="hero-banner__content">
    <h1>Awesome Banner Content</h1>
    <p>This is some text content appearing on top of the video.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

## **Style of hero banner:**

**Approach 1:**

```
.hero-banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  &__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;

    &::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #01f150;
      mix-blend-mode: color;
    }
  }

  &__content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
.hero-banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  &__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  &__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #01f150;
    mix-blend-mode: color;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  &__content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

I tried using `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` as well, which works on iPhones and iPads Safari with expected tint shade but on Chrome it's behaving differently.

Additionally, I have used the same property with banner images or overlay on hover effect for some components and it's working for every component except `<video>` component.